# Angularjs and nested JSON and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have inherited code from another person who is no longer on the project, and I am still working on the paradigm shift to Angular alone (no one here to bounce ideas off of), so have a question for the group.

I am getting JSON that has two nodes that I need to iterate over. The JSON is shown here:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "text": "Do you plan to attend the session on 6/3 at 12?",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9LUL3A",
                    "display": "Yes",
                    "value": "Yes"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9LUL3A",
                    "display": "No",
                    "value": "No"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "When you get the meeting/appointment invite accept it with the Notes client (as opposed to the iDevice)",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9NFPMZ",
                    "display": "September 1, 2014 12:00 PM - 01:00 PM",
                    "value": "09/01/2014~12:00:00 PM~01:00:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9NFPMZ",
                    "display": "September 1, 2014 01:00 PM - 02:00 PM",
                    "value": "09/01/2014~01:00:00 PM~02:00:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9NFPMZ",
                    "display": "September 1, 2014 02:00 PM - 03:00 PM",
                    "value": "09/01/2014~02:00:00 PM~03:00:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer_9NFPMZ",
                    "display": "September 1, 2014 03:00 PM - 04:00 PM",
                    "value": "09/01/2014~03:00:00 PM~04:00:00 PM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to display the questions.text and underneath it I need to display the questions.choices.display for each question. N number of questions with n number of answers. Like so...

Example:

```
Q1 How are you?
A1 Feelin' Fine
A2 Fair
A3 Feelin' Bad

Q1 Where are you?
A1 Beach in Bahamas
A2 Broadway in New York
A3 Prison in Leavenworth
```

What is the best/proper way to use ng-repeat in this case? Should I have one array that contains the question and its answers and have ng-repeats over the parts that I need where I need them, or break it into two arrays (question and answers) and mix/nest the two?  The latter seems possibly problematic.

Disclaimer: I am recovering from kidney stone surgery and on pain meds, so I'm having trouble visualizing the right answer. Please don't dog pile, I'm hurting and in a daze.

I thank everyone in advance.

Comment: A nested ng-repeat using your existing json structure should work. Outer ng-repeat for questions, inner for answers for that question.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the reply. It seems trivial now, but when coding alone, other voices and opinions are so helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't apologize at all. Hope you have a quick recovery.

Now, about your question, I've done similar things using a nested ng-repeat approach.

```
<div ng-controller='QuestionsController as questionList'>
    <div ng-repeat='question in questionList.questions'>
        {{ question.text }}
        <div ng-repeat='choice in question.choices'>
            {{ choice.display }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course you would use your custom directives and whatnot. Best of luck in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer, the visual and the kind reply!